# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error,,

Tags: javascript

i found an error in this code (the error is in value)

```
run = async (message) => {
  let totelMembers = 0
  for (const guild of this.client.guilds.cache) {
    totalMembers += (await guild[1].members.fetch()).size
  }
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(
    `Information about the ${this.client.username} Bot`,
    this.client.user.displayAvatarURL()
  )
  .addFields(
    {
      name: 'Total members'
      value: totalMembers,
    },
    {
      name: 'bot tag'
      value: this.client.user.tag
    },
  )
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

(sorry if i didn't type will because my english is not good)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, you missed commas in the embed fields:

```js
...
  .addFields(
    {
      name: 'Total members', // here a comma
      value: totalMembers,
    },
    {
      name: 'bot tag', // here a comma
      value: this.client.user.tag
    },
  )
...
```

Also, you can use another way to add fields if you want, just try

```js
.addField( name, value )
```